# ExtJS 4.2 - JSON store from asmx not showing items

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, extjs, extjs4

I have a JSON store which read data from webservice.
The JSON from the webservice is valid (I've tried reading the data directly from file and it was working).

Here is the JSON Data:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Points",
"keyField": "GPSUserName",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                35.19999,
                31.780965
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "GPSId": "<img src=images/battery3.png />",
            "DateTime": "12/07/2013 09:05:00",
            "GPSUserName": "13",
            "GPSUserColor": "#00FF57",
            "GPSUserIcon": "marker_red2.png",
            "GPSLabelPosX": "6",
            "GPSLabelPosY": "7"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                35.201142,
                31.780699
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "GPSId": "<img src=images/battery4.png />",
            "DateTime": "12/07/2013 09:05:00",
            "GPSUserName": "14",
            "GPSUserColor": "#00FF57",
            "GPSUserIcon": "marker_red2.png",
            "GPSLabelPosX": "6",
            "GPSLabelPosY": "7"
        }
    }
]
```

}

When using the following store , everything is working fine :

```
 initComponent: function () {

    this.store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        storeId: 'usersStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: false,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data/users.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'features'
            }
        },
        fields: [
            { name: 'name', mapping: 'properties.GPSUserName'},
            { name: 'date', mapping: 'properties.DateTime' },
            { name: 'battery', mapping: 'properties.GPSId' }
        ]
    });

    this.columns = [
        { header: 'name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1 },
        { header: 'date', dataIndex: 'date', flex: 3 },
        { header: 'battery', dataIndex: 'battery', flex: 1 }
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

but when I change to use a webservice (which returns the file content) nothing works:

```
 initComponent: function () {

    this.store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        storeId: 'usersStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: false,
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'service.asmx/GetJson',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;' },
            reader: { root: 'd', record: 'features' }
        }),  

        fields: [
            { name: 'name', mapping: 'properties.GPSUserName'},
            { name: 'date', mapping: 'properties.DateTime' },
            { name: 'battery', mapping: 'properties.GPSId' }
        ]
    });                  

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

and this is the webservice :

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public string GetJson()
    {
        string res = File.ReadAllText("data\users.json");
        return res;
        /*HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(res);*/
    }
```

In firebug I see the following returns from the call :
[image]

So ... what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is the buggy implementation of ExtJS `JsonStore` in ExtJS 4.2.  If you look at the source code of this class, you will see that it is ignoring your proxy configuration:

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.JsonStore',  {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.json',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json',
        'Ext.data.writer.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(config) {
        config = Ext.apply({
            proxy: {
                type  : 'ajax',
                reader: 'json',
                writer: 'json'
            }
        }, config);
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

Just use the `Ext.data.Store` class and everything should be find.  Lost a lot of time on this before figuring this out.